# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException for empty list

Tags: list, groovy, runtime-error, groovyshell

Why an empty list from [Groovy Tutorial](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+1+-+Getting+started) throws a runtime error **MissingPropertyException**?

The code is simple:

```
groovy:000> emptylist = []
groovy:000> print emptyList
```

The groovy shell error message is below:

```
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
No such property: emptyList for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
```

**Update**:

Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.6.0_45 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux

Comment: Probably You need to use `def` keyword? It works fine with groovy v. 2.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a spelling mistake (`l` vs. `L`).

Comment: Yeah. So light issue. Thanks.